# por que muestra webcam en localhost y no en el servidor?

Tags: php, javascript, servidor, localhost, qr

estoy desarrollando un scaner qr, resulta que funciona de maravilla en localhost, pero al momento de subirlo al servidor y probarlo, no funciona, la cámara no aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilizo https://webqr.com/, exactamente el mismo codigo, pero a ellos si le funciona en su servidor, alguna recomendacion de por donde empezar para detectar el error?

les dejo aqui el url de la web de la imagen:
[URL PAGINA DE PRUEBA](http://saltapersonalizados.com/_app/)

desde ya, muchas gracias, cualquier recomendación se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu sitio, en en script `webqr.js` en la `línea 198` esta esto:

```
n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: options, audio: false}).
    then(function(stream){
        success(stream);
    }).catch(function(error){
        error(error)
    });
```

Cambiale el nombre al parametro `error`... por ejemplo:

```
n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: options, audio: false}).
    then(function(stream){
        success(stream);
    }).catch(function(e){
        error(e);
    });
```

En tu caso el error que está sacando es por esa línea (no se si después te puedan salir mas errores, pero el actual es ese, que una función y una variable se llaman igual y se usan en el mismo contexto)

Comment: gracias, no había notado ese error, pero aun así, eso no provoca el error que necesito solucionar, la cámara sigue sin aparecer en el servidor, alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Que dice la consola de javascript? algun otro error?

Comment: Veo que ya actualizaste el código en el servidor... el problema actual sale en la consola: `webqr.js:198 [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.` Lo que significa que ese metodo para obtener la camara no puede ser usado en dominios sin certificado SSL. Debes instalarle un certificado HTTPS en tu dominio para que se pueda acceder con  `https://saltaperzonalizados.com/_app`... por eso SI funciona en `https://webqr.com`

Comment: gracias, alguna recomendación de como usar la cámara sin certificados SSL?

Comment: No hay recomendación, simplemente "no se puede"... porque es inseguro y cualquiera podría expiar las conversaciones o ver el video capturado.

Comment: perfecto, he visto algunos complementos para lograrlo, pero al parecer ya son obsoletos, ej probé adapter.js de webrtc, hasta encontré un ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/srn9db4h/ , pero no me funciono, tendré que pagar el SSL, no queda otra, gracias por toda la ayuda, saludos.

Comment: @AugustoDanielRuyz Podrías usar AppEngine de GCP para hacer tus pruebas, te brinda el certificado SSL gratuito

Comment: @EdHuamani gracias, pero la app ya esta terminada, utilice localhost para realizar las pruebas, solo necesito que permiso del navegador a la cámara en protocolos no seguros, osea, para que funcione desde la pagina oficial, si llego a encontrar algo, lo publico, pero lo dudo, como dijo Pipe simplemente no se puede.

Comment: @AugustoDanielRuyz Pipe tiene razón, también puedes generar certificado gratuito en https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: gracias! de veras! me salvaron! estuve investigando un poco sobre los SSL gratuitos ( https://blog.infranetworking.com/ssl-tradicional-vs-cloudflare-vs-lets-encrypt/ ) y opte por usar el SSL de CloudFlare, la encriptacion no es completa de punta a punta, pero puedo agregarlo solo con cambiar los DNS de mi dominio, y creo que sera suficiente para que reconozca el sitio como seguro, me hubiera gustado usar LetsEncryt, pero mi hosting no me da la opción de agregar certificados, y la empresa me cobra por agregarlo, y aunque sea gratuito hay que renovarlo cada 90 días.